# CRM: Javascript to Set Multiple Email Addresses when Replying to an Email

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

On CRM 2013 I'm trying to insert multiple participants into the email "to" field when users click on "Reply All". However I need to remove certain email addresses from the To line. So I created an array to loop and get all the email addresses except the one that needs to be removed.

However the problem here is that it only works if there is only one participant left after removing the unwanted participants. If there are two or more participants the script will not populate any participants at all.

Is there a way to populate multiple email participants? Or is there a better approach than what I'm trying to do here?

Here's my code:

```
var toParty = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue();

var partyListArray = new Array();
for (var indxAttendees = 0; indxAttendees < toParty.length; indxAttendees++) {
  // using oData to get participant email address
  var email = getParticipantEmail(
    toParty[indxAttendees].entityType, 
    toParty[indxAttendees].id
  );
  if (email != "test@test.com") {
    partyListArray[indxAttendees] = new Object();
    partyListArray[indxAttendees].id = toParty[indxAttendees].id;
    partyListArray[indxAttendees].name = toParty[indxAttendees].name;
    partyListArray[indxAttendees].entityType = toParty[indxAttendees].entityType;
  }
}

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").setValue(null);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").setValue(partyListArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a whole new array, you can delete what you want from the array itself. Try this:

```js
var emails = [{email: "add1@domain.com"}, {email: "add2@domain.com"}, {email: "address@toBe.Removed"},  {email: "add3@domain.com"}, {email: "add4@domain.com"}];

var removeIndex = emails.map(function(item) { return item.email; }).indexOf("address@toBe.Removed");

removeIndex > -1 && emails.splice(removeIndex, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you this is a good suggestion. There could be more than 1 removed emails so I put the removeIndex into an array, then delete from there.